# Bash process substitution in string

Tags: bash, shell, process, substitution

I'm trying to add a switch to a script which will make a parameter on an internal command optional. Normally, I'd do this by either using a conditional to run the command with the parameter or without it, or if the parameter is simple, just create a string with the parameter in and substitute that. If the parameter is not needed then the string is just empty.

I have the added complexity that there's a dry run mode which just prints the command rather than running it so there's already one conditional. For this reason, I just wanted to create the internal parameter as a string and then substitute it either in the `echo` of the dry run, or the real command. However, the option is a little complex and looks like this:

```
<(echo $msg_enc | base64 -d -)
```

This takes a string encoded in base64, decodes it and presents the contents as a temporary file which can be read. I can't really change this structure easily, so I'm trying to work out how I can keep this in a string and evaluate it. To do this I created a shell script, `call_just_print.sh` and another tiny shell script to mimic the command, `just_print.sh`

**call_just_print.sh**

```
msg="hello world"
msg_enc="$(echo $msg | base64)"

dry_run=0
if [[ "${1}" == "dry-run" ]]; then
    dry_run=1
fi

enc_cmd=" <(echo \$msg_enc | base64 -d -)"
if [[ "${dry_run}" == "1" ]]; then
    echo "./just_print.sh ${enc_cmd}"
else
    ./just_print.sh "${enc_cmd}"
fi
```

This really just picks up a dry run hint from the command line and, if set, simply prints the command it's going to run, or if not set, will run the command.

**just_print.sh**

```
echo "[$(cat ${1})]"
```

This trivially receives a parameter which it assumes to be a file and displays it to the terminal. Ideally, the output would print `[hello world]` when run without dry-run mode. When I run it, I get the following:

```
$ ./call_just_print.sh dry-run
./just_print.sh  <(echo $msg_enc | base64 -d -)
$ ./call_just_print.sh
cat: invalid option -- 'd'
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
[]
```

The dry-run mode works fine but when used without the flag, the `msg_enc` var is passed verbatim to `just_print.sh` resulting in the following being run: `cat '<(echo' '$msg_enc' '|' base64 -d '-)'` which is absolutely not right.

I tried using `eval` in the call as follows:

```
./just_print.sh "$(eval ${enc_cmd})"
```

but I found that while this results in the correct evaluation of the variable resulting in creation of the temporary file, it then tries to execute it:

```
./call_just_print.sh: line 15: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Shell operators are not processed when you expand a variable. You need to use `eval` to get it to re-parse after expanding the variable.

Comment: If your version of `base64` splits long output into lines, `echo $msg_enc` will effectively turn the line breaks into spaces, causing a decode error. Use `echo "$msg_enc"` to preserve the newlines, which'd mean using something like `enc_cmd=" <(echo \"\$msg_enc\" | base64 -d -)"`

Comment: Also, encoding "hello world" and "hello world\n" give different results: `printf '%s' "$msg_enc" | base64 -w0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
    ./just_print.sh "${enc_cmd}"
```

to

```
    eval "./just_print.sh ${enc_cmd}"
```

so it will evaluate the result of the variable expansion as shell code. Otherwise it's treated as a literal argument to `just_print.sh`.

Be very careful when using `eval` -- the code to be executed should be generated by your script, not user-provided.

Comment: I didn't even dare to suggest it :-)

Comment: I added a caveat about not using user-generated input.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
msg="hello world"
msg_enc="$(echo $msg | base64)"

dry_run="eval"
if [[ "${1}" == "dry-run" ]]; then
    dry_run="echo"
fi

enc_cmd=" <(echo \$msg_enc | base64 -d -)"
$dry_run "./just_print.sh ${enc_cmd}"
```

You were on the right track with `eval`, but you over-complicated it. You just needed to restructure it so that the whole command was `eval`ed.

I also simplified your logic so that dry run commands and executed commands are unified, avoiding ugly and error-prone `if` blocks.

Comment: ah, guess I am a little late to the party; so busy working on it I didn't notice someone else had answered it while I was working on it.